# cURL including garbage when redirecting stderr to stdout

Tags: bash, macos, unix, curl

I'm using curl 7.54.1 (x86_64-apple-darwin15.6.0) to download a track from the soundcloud API in a bash script

The code looks like this -

```
# -vsLOJ = --verbose --silent --location --remote-name --remote-header-name
# redirect stderr to stdout to capture the headers
curl_output=$(curl -vsLOJ $track_download_url?client_id=$client_id 2>&1);
```

This is supposed to:

1. verbosely print out the request/response (to capture HTTP headers)
2. silence the download bar
3. follow the location (the API provides a pretty link that 302's to the actual file)
4. Create a file using "Content-Disposition" header as the file name (this becomes the output file, not `stdout`)
5. redirect stderr (where the verbose output is sent) to stdout

What's happening:
The download is OK, it saves the file to the working directory with the correct name from "Content-Disposition" *but* `$curl_output` is filled with garbage data of what looks like a mix of an `ls` of the working directory and *partial* verbose data.

Example output cURL-ing `https://www.google.com` in a test directory with files:

```
curl_output=$(curl --verbose -o /dev/null "https://www.google.com" 2>&1)
echo $curl_output
```

> fakefile.1 fakefile.2 hello.txt song.mp3 vacation.png Rebuilt URL to:
>   https://www.google.com/ fakefile.1 fakefile.2 hello.txt song.mp3
>   vacation.png Trying 172.217.10.100... fakefile.1 fakefile.2 hello.txt
>   song.mp3 vacation.png TCP_NODELAY set fakefile.1 fakefile.2 hello.txt
>   song.mp3 vacation.png Connected to www.google.com (172.217.10.100)
>   port 443 (#0) fakefile.1 fakefile.2 hello.txt song.mp3 vacation.png
>   TLS 1.2 connection using TLS_ECDHE_RSA_WITH_AES_128_GCM_SHA256
>   fakefile.1 fakefile.2 hello.txt song.mp3 vacation.png Server
>   certificate: www.google.com fakefile.1 fakefile.2 hello.txt song.mp3
>   vacation.png Server certificate: Google Internet Authority G2
>   fakefile.1 fakefile.2 hello.txt song.mp3 vacation.png Server
>   certificate: GeoTrust Gl < Set-Cookie:
>   REDACTED=REDACTED######################################################################## 100.0%* Connection #0 to host www.google.com left intact

Completely confusing to me. I've tested this in a bash script and from Terminal. It only seems to be happening when I store the result in a variable, running that cURL (including the stderr redirect) without storing it in $curl_output will correctly write

And, this is happening for any URL I test with

My .curlrc:

```
user-agent = "Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10_19_4) AppleWebKit/603.4.1 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/59.0.3050.56 Safari/603.4.1"
referer = ";auto"
connect-timeout = 10
progress-bar
max-time = 90
remote-time
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Put quotes around your `$curl_output` variable, because it contains `*` which get interpreted.

```
% echo "$curl_output"
* Rebuilt URL to: https://www.google.com/
  % Total    % Received % Xferd  Average Speed   Time    Time     Time  Current
                                 Dload  Upload   Total   Spent    Left  Speed
  0     0    0     0    0     0      0      0 --:--:-- --:--:-- --:--:--     0*   Trying 2a00:1450:4009:806::2004...
* Connected to www.google.com (2a00:1450:4009:806::2004) port 443 (#0)
* TLS 1.2 connection using TLS_ECDHE_RSA_WITH_AES_128_GCM_SHA256
```

Whereas:

```
echo $curl_output
```

would resolve the `*` into whatever files names are lying in your current directory.

Comment: Thank you! Did not realize that bash expands the variable before execution